# mount: /oldssd: special device /dev/sda2/ does not exist (a path prefix is not a directory)

Tags: ssd, mount, fedora, fstab

Today my new SSD arrived from Amazon. I installed the SSD and Fedora 31 onto it. I still have my old ssd plugged in.

When I try to mount it by the path `/oldssd` I get error `mount: /oldssd: special device /dev/sda2/ does not exist (a path prefix is not a directory).`. Everything seems to be correct in my /etc/fstab since I can mount by using the device path `/dev/sda2`

What gives?

```
[root@teckno-fedora2 ~]# tail /etc/fstab -n1
/dev/sda2/ /oldssd ext4 defaults 0 0
[root@teckno-fedora2 ~]# 
[root@teckno-fedora2 ~]# mount /oldssd/
mount: /oldssd: special device /dev/sda2/ does not exist (a path prefix is not a directory).
[root@teckno-fedora2 ~]# 
[root@teckno-fedora2 ~]# mount /dev/sda2
[root@teckno-fedora2 ~]# 
[root@teckno-fedora2 ~]# ls /oldssd/
backup  checksums_backup.md5
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remove that trailing slash after sda2 in fstab.

So it says /dev/sda2 instead of /dev/sda2/

sda2 isn't a directory, but a special file.

It's file type is block-device.

Comment: +1 for the extra comment "sda2 isn't a directory, but a special file": very enlightening

Comment: It's actually one of the most important things to learn about Linux (any POSIX compliant OS). -->Every supported hardware device is represented by a file somewhere.